# How can I convert uppercase letters to lowercase in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, case-sensitive

I use Notepad ++ for coding mostly.

How can I convert capital letters to lowercase and vice versa?

Answer (score 411, accepted):

Just select the text you want to change, right click and select UPPERCASE or lowercase depending on what you want.

Comment: I look at this and want to change the capital of each word (making the first letter of each word capital). Can notepad++ do that?

Comment: @LucVu: This is called Title Case, Notepad++ calls it Proper Case and the answer is here: http://superuser.com/questions/115432/converting-text-to-title-case-in-notepad

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl+Shift+U` for UPPERCASE and `Ctrl+U` for lowercase if you like shortcut keys.

Comment: Just an FYI: If you are using Visual Studio 2015 these shortcuts work directly in the code editor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Notepad++ v6.2.3 on Windows 7). Only the `Ctrl+Shift+U`/`Ctrl+U` or [SQL_Novice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36546699/6689867) work.

Answer (score 160):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

should do the trick!

Edit:   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>   is the shortcut to be used to convert capital letters to lowercase (reverse scenario)

Comment: Ctrl+U for convert back to small letters

Comment: CTRL+A is select all.

Answer (score 60):

First select the text
To convert lowercase to uppercase, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
To convert uppercase to lowercase, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 21):

In my notepad++ I press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> =  To select all words

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> = To convert lowercase

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> = To convert uppercase

Answer (score 4):

You could also, higlight the text you want to change, then navigate to - 'Edit' > 'Convert Case to' choose UPPERCASE or lowercase (as required).

Answer (score 3):

I had to transfer texts from an Excel file to an xliff file. We had some texts that were originally in uppercase but those translators didn't use uppercase so I used notepad++ as intermediate to do the conversion.

Since I had the mouse in one hand (to mark in Excel and activate the different windows) I disliked the predefined shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) as "U" is too far away for my left hand.
I first switched it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> which worked.

Then I realized, that you can create macros easily, so I recorded one doing:

- mark all
- paste from clipboard
- convert to upppercase
- copy to clipboard

That macro got assigned that very shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and made my life easy :)