# replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a string in this kind:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN ('A' , 'stu' ,'Meyer', ....);
```

I want replace all characters in notepad++ from upper to lower (or vice versa) BUT, exclude from replacement, characters inside single quotation marks.

> **condition:** It exists no solid structure before/behind the single quotation marks part!
>
> (That means - I can not use the keyword "IN" or signs like "," or "("
>   or ")" or ";" for this regex ...!)

**target string** (the characters inside single quotation marks have to stay unchangend):

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name in ('A' , 'stu' ,'Meyer', ....);
```

OR (vice versa)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('A' , 'stu' ,'Meyer', ....);
```

**How can I exclude in notepad++ the single quotation marks part (from replacement)?**

(I find the single quotation marks part with e.g. '(.*?)' or '(\w+)' or '[[:alpha:]]{1,}',..)

I'm happy for every answer, also if you don't use notepad++!

Comment: If you just want to convert before opening `(` search for `^(.*?\()` and replace with `\U\1` or lower: `\L\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex would match all the uppercase letters which are not present inside single quotes.

```
[A-Z](?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'\n])*$)
```

[Now, right-click on the matched characters and  change it to  lowercase.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879623/convert-all-capital-letters-to-simple-letters-in-notepad)

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xF1iQ0/2)

Comment: many, many thanks (also for your effort) - that is what I needed - perfect

Comment: I know it's probably obvious, but how do you select the text using that regex? I tried `Search-Mark...`, and it does mark the text but doesn't select it so I can convert the case.