# replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025638/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)

*Sorry to all users (especially to Avinash Raj) who answered already 1st similiar question - I did simply forget the 2nd kind of string.
(And (that is the sad thing) - I'm not able to adjust the solution from 1st similiar question to the 2nd kind of string...)*

I have TWO different strings in this kind:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);
WHERE    a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATEerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
```

I want replace all characters in notepad++ from upper to lower, BUT exclude from replacement characters inside
single quotation marks.

> **condition:** It exists no solid structure before/behind/between the single quotation marks part!
>
> (That means - I can not use the
>   keyword "IN" or signs like "," or "(" or ")" or ";" for this regex
>   ...!)
>
> The once thing is, that two structures for single quotation marks are possible:
>   ***'Word|Number'*** or ***''Word|Number''***
>   (but, as shown in 2nd example, with different number of spaces between every single quotation mark!).

**target string** (the characters inside single quotation marks have to stay unchangend):

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name in ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);
where    a.object_type in (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
```

**How can I exclude in notepad++ the single quotation marks part (from replacement)?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025638/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could combine a [recursive](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) part for getting `'`... `'`.... `abc` `''` and use [\K for resetting](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) after. This is the part that needs to be skipped. And using kind of [the trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick), matching remaining words in pipe:

```
'\s*(?0)?[^']*'\K|(\w+)
```

- `(?0)?` here the pattern is optionally pasted from start
- `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *whitespace character* `[ \t\r\n\f]`
- `\w` is a short for *word character* `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

And replace with `\L\1` to lower words captured inside the first capture group or `\U\1` to upper.

Works for me in *NP++ 6.7.9.2* with your sample data. [See regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kY9zO2/1) for testing the pattern.

[image]

Comment: Hi and Sorry for my next mistake - your solution for this case is o.k. but I posted only a part of the whole 2nd statement (stupid)- can you also try to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @ora_job, where does it not work as expected? Just made a little modification!

Comment: I post the whole statement in the next comment: (the problem what I didn't mention is - the ''Word/Number'' part is additional included in global single quotation marks - please look at the beginning and the end of the whole 2nd statement...)

Comment: SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name in ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);
THEN vpl_sql_string := 
'
SELECT  b.mview_name
FROM   all_objects@'|| pi_2 ||'   a
  ,user_mviews     b
  ,user_mview_detail_relations c
WHERE  a.object_type IN (''TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'')
 AND  a.owner   =  UPPER( :bi_1 )
 AND  a.object_name  = c.detailobj_name
 AND  b.mview_name = c.mview_name
 AND (
   b.refresh_method = ''COMPLETE''
  OR
            (b.refresh_method  = ''FORCE''
AND b.last_refresh_type = ''COMPLETE''))
AND  TO_DATE(a.timestamp,''YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'') > b.last_refresh_date ';

Comment: Sorry for this fomat - it was correct formatted, but to much signs for input box - that's why it looks so terrible....

Comment: @ora_job please include your sample in your question as code block.

Comment: Please wait with your solution - I open part3, with correct formatting!