# replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(3rd)

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

*[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025638/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)
[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037307/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)*

*Sorry, sorry to all users (especially to Avinash Raj + Jonny 5) who answered already successfull 1st/2nd similiar question...*

Here is now the whole statement part:

(the problem what I didn't mention is - the ''Word/Number'' part is additional included in global single quotation marks - please look 
at the beginning and the end of the whole 2nd statement...)

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name in ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);

THEN    vpl_sql_string := 
    '
    SELECT   b.mview_name   -- use this
    FROM     all_objects@'|| pi_2 ||'       a   -- master_site
            ,user_mviews                    b   -- slave_site
            ,user_mview_detail_relations    c   -- slave_site
    WHERE    a.object_type IN ' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
        AND  a.owner        =   UPPER( :bi_1 )
        AND  a.object_name  = c.detailobj_name
        AND  b.mview_name   = c.mview_name
        AND (
                b.refresh_method = ''COMPLETE''
            OR
                (
                    b.refresh_method    = ''FORCE''
                AND b.last_refresh_type = ''COMpleTE''
                )
            )
        AND  TO_DATE(a.timestamp,''YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'') > b.last_refresh_date   '
        || vppgc_sql_string_master_link || ' :bi_2 )    '  ;
```

**conditions** (stay the same like in):

*[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037307/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)*

> (it's enough, when the whole 2nd statement is not touched by regex!
>   The regex don't have to exchange the values between the "*global single
>   quotation marks*"!)

**How can I exclude in notepad++ the single quotation marks part (from replacement)?**

Answer (score 0):

the correct solution for my question is/was alraedy correct answered by @Jonny 5 - this solution is also correct for the whole 2nd statement
( I was confused...)

[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037307/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)